# Selection of Open GL2 ES image fragment

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I have a so library for render OpenGL image on GLSurfaceView. This library include a method that takes rectangle as argument. How i can do instrument for select fragment (portion) of OpenGL image ?
Code for render image using this library:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (mLoaded != true && mWidth != 0 && mHeight != 0) {
        mContextCreated = true;
        CloudJNI.init();
        CloudJNI.open(mFile);
        CloudJNI.createRenderer(mWidth, mHeight);
        mLoaded = true;
    }
    if (mContextCreated == true) {
        if (!CloudJNI.renderFrame()) {

            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Make clearer what does "How I can do instrument for select fragment (portion) of OpenGL Image" mean. Instrument what? The word fragment has a set of meanings in OpenGL 2) If the library is open source provide a link.

Comment: Istrument for selection region of OpenGL image. No, library doenst' open source.